# How do I correct this use of ui-router multiple named views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to setup a page that has no parent template but contains multiple named views using angular ui-router.

[A plunkr is here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zHwbbL06zF8Nl0R0Ey60)

There is a simple html setup:

```
<body>
  <div ng-app="thing">
    <h1>Multiple Views</h1>
    <div ui-view="oneThing"></div>
    <div ui-view="twoThing"></div>
    <div ui-view="threeThing"></div>

    <script id="one_thing.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <p>one: {{text}}</p>
    </script>
    <script id="two_thing.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <p>two: {{text}}</p>
    </script>    
    <script id="three_thing.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <p>three: {{text}}</p>
    </script>
  </div>
  </body>
```

I expect this to mean I have three views and three templates that the 'thing' app can see

Then the JS setup is:

```
'use strict';

var thing = angular.module("thing", ['ui.router']);

thing.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('things', {
        url: '/things', 
        views: {
          'oneThing': {
            templateUrl:'one_thing.html',
            controller: 'oneCtrl'
          },
          'twoThing': {
            templateUrl:'two_thing.html',
            controller: 'twoCtrl'
          },
          'threeThing': {
            templateUrl:'three_thing.html',
            controller: 'threeCtrl'
          }
      }
  });
  $urlRouterProvider.when('/', 'things');
});

thing.controller('oneCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.text = 'boom';
});

thing.controller('twoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.text = 'bang';
});

thing.controller('threeCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.text = 'wallop';
});
```

I thought this meant always load 'things' as the route and within that state load three views each pointing to a different template and controller. But instead I get a blank page...

Have I misunderstood how this works or how to write it (or, worse, both!!)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default url is  not `/`

So `$urlRouterProvider.when('/', 'things');` is not being triggered.

Change to

`$urlRouterProvider.when('', 'things');`

and your plunkr works.

Comment: Or, of course put `$urlRouterProvider.when('', '/');`

Comment: Ah, Doh! I had a feeling the problem was between my ears. Thankyou!